# When should a task be executed asynchronously vs on the main thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperation

I understand that all changes to the views should be on the main thread, but at what level of complexity should I start to consider using `dispatch_async`?

Should it be used for:
- number crunching (like computing a complex probability)
- saving to some form of persistent storage
- updating a model object
- initializing bulky objects

I'm comfortable with iOS until it comes to threading. I always do asynchronous network requests, but aside from that I just try to use minimal resources on the main thread and that still makes for a slightly laggy app.

I searched multiple sources for this so if there is a similar question, point it out and forgive my ignorance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most things that are not UI-related, but might adversely affect the responsiveness of your app, are all candidates for tasks to be moved to the background queue. Don't worry about not being comfortable yet, but some of these resources might help:

- [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH1-SW1)
- WWDC 2012 - [Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=211)
- WWDC 2011 - [Mastering Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=210)
- WWDC 2011 - [Blocks and Grand Central Dispatch in Practice](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=308)
- [Synchronization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW1) section of the *Threading Programming Guide* (and the relevant [Eliminating Lock-Based Code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW3) from the *Concurrent Programming Guide* referenced above, which briefly describes how to achieve synchronization without locks)

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful links. Let me just pose this question to get it out of my head- would it be anything other than insensitive design to make every non-UI task asynchronous?

Comment: @user I wouldn't be inclined to make _every_ non-UI task asynchronous. I would counsel a more pragmatic approach, that anything that affects app responsiveness be considered a candidate for asynchronous design. Proper asynchronous design is not always trivial (e.g. the need to synchronize objects/variables being accessed from multiple threads), so I'd suggest you go through that effort when required rather than on principle.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple answer: The device should be responsive, i.e. react to user interactions as far as possible immediately. Thus any operation that takes more than a fraction of a second should be executed as a separate thread, whenever possible.
Of course multithreading can be tricky, but if the threads are well separated, it is rather straightforward. The most important thing one has to keep in mind is that most classes of the UIKit, and many other classes like arrays are not thread-safe, and accessing them from multiple threads must be synchronized, e.g. by using a `@synchronize` block. So, read the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/AboutThreads/AboutThreads.html), e.g. here, carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Profile your app. Seriously, nothing else will tell you where exactly your app becomes laggy. I've seen unexpected bottlenecks like `UILabel` rendering and string processing in my own code. Without **Instruments** I would never even consider optimizing them.